# Is our app certified according to Mobile Application Security Assessment Framework?

Tags: android, google-play-console

Recently play store added new question

- Is your app currently certified by an authorised lab, according to the Mobile Application Security Assessment (MASA) framework? Learn about how you should answer. (Yes / No)

https://appdefensealliance.dev/masa

I don't understand what to select. Is my app is supported MASA?

Comment: Have you got your app certified by anyone, a company, or an authorized body that follows MASA protocols? ( i think not )  .Then the answer is 'NO'.

Comment: I didn't get any certificate @HeshanSandeepa

Comment: Then select the answer as 'NO'

Comment: And if you select no, is the lab review mandatory or a nice-to-have thing ?

Answer (score 3):

It depends on whether you got your app tested by an authorized lab or not.

The answer would be "No" if your app was not certified by an authorized lab and "Yes" if your app has been certified by an authorized lab .

Note: The lab needs to follow the "Mobile Application Security Assessment" standard framework to certify your app .